# PostgreSQL IN operator with lots of values in an external file

Tags: postgresql

I have a file with a lot of identifiers, one in each line. I also have a DB with a superset of those id's. I would like to query the DB only with the id's of interest. Is there a way to "import" an external file or do I have to copy all 300 values into the IN expression? This is a large db.

Comment: Define "large." We've all come across people who think a few thousand rows is "large" even though most relational DBs can power through them like a hot knife through butter. =) It's much better to speak of actual sizes or, even better, rough row counts (with at *least* correct order of magnitude).

Comment: @jpmc26: 60 million :S

Comment: Who owns/controls the file?  Is it under the same ownership/control as the database itself?  How often does it change?

Comment: @DervinThunk do these answers satisfy the question? Can you mark one as chosen if so?

Answer (score 5):

Sure, either,

1. Use a CTE with a `VALUES` statement.
2. Use a [`TEMP` table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html) with an index.

Here is an example with the CTE.

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT * FROM ( VALUES
    (1),
    (2),
    (3)
  ) AS t(table_id)
)
SELECT * FROM t
JOIN myTable
  USING (table_id)
;
```

Only slightly more complex is getting them into a temp table which permits you to index it. You can also use the [Foreign Data Wrapper](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html) create a FOREIGN TABLE if you have an [*external file*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/file-fdw.html) depending on the format. Try it without an index, and copy it into a table and see if an index speeds it up.

Answer (score 4):

If you can run command from shell (better if it is Unix/Mac, but probably may be Windows), you can run something like this for integer/float/number:

```
echo "SELECT * FROM table WHERE field IN ("`cat < 000.file  | awk '{printf("%s,", $1)}' | sed 's/,$//g'`")" | psql db
```

Or something like this for varchar, timestamp, etc:

```
 echo "SELECT * FROM table WHERE field IN ("`cat < 000.file  | awk '{printf("_%s_,", $1)}' | sed 's/,$//g' | sed "s/_/\'/g"`")" | psql db
```